# Append Items to asp:Listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

Can anyone suggest me a way to Append Listbox items when i already have items in my `asp:listbox`

so far I have tried this :

```
ListItem Li=new ListItem(objSubscriber.FirstName,objSubscriber
                                       .SubscriberID.ToString());
lstboxSubscribers.Items.Insert(lstboxSubscribers.Items.Count + 1, Li);
```

is there any way to find out last index of a listbox for the existing preloaded listbox? like `LastIndexOf()` or something similar

it's throwing an `indexoutofrange Exception` 
if more clarifications are required, I will provide it.
any workarounds?

Comment: your problem might be `lstboxSubscribers.Items.Count + 1` since Items is *zero indexed*, try without the `+ 1` part !

Comment: Did you try by removing the + 1 part in your current code ?

Comment: yupp now it worked and also the appenddataboundiems property to true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 will return the lastIndex of ListBox
```

Set `AppendDataBoundItems="true"` and it will append the items in the existing listItems.

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true"></asp:ListBox>
```

Comment: @M. Akhtar i try and let you know

Answer (score 1):

try just using

```
lstboxSubscribers.Items.Add(Li);
```

Comment: it will not append but clear the exisiting items and add the new ones

Comment: @devjosh if you're doing it after a postback make sure the other items are filled in the load or in the aspx file otherwise you will start with an empty box

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this in codebehind `yourlistbox.Items.Add(li);` or if you databind to list box try         `yourlistboxid.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
                yourlistboxid.DataSource = datasource1;
                yourlistboxid.DataBind();`